# Woocommerce - Increase number of product variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product with 300+ variations. I'm displaying all variations in one large form, because i want the user to pick various variations to buy at once.

[image]

When i add to cart it doesn't work, but if i choose a product that has less number of variations, it works normal.

I've alredy changed my max_input_vars in my php.ini.

How i increment the number of variations?

URL: http://patricio.jhkon.site/index.php/product/regular-t-shirt-man/

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong way to do this task. color should be the attribute to size should be the variation. and you can create a custom fucntion to choose the color for the product. you can create the a dropdown list where user can select the color and from size variation user can select the variation.

if you want to create dropdown using product atrributes. Let me know.

Comment: I forgot to add this, but i have 2 ways to add to cart. The first one has a similar logic that you are suggesting, with dropdowns. The second one is the matrix that the client wants. Thank you for the suggestion.